# Can I use DEFAULT constraint with multiple values in MySQL? Can I add more default values in the example below?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (

    Code int NOT NULL,
    Last_Name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    First_Name varchar(25),
    Age int(2),
    City varchar(30) DEFAULT 'KAJI'

);
```

Comment: What do you mean? DEFAULT with multiple values? Please add some details to your question as it is very much unclear.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to have multiple default value option for a single column? If so no only one default value per column is possible

Comment: DEFAULT is not a constraint..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am following you correctly then you are talking about the following line:

```
...
City varchar(30) DEFAULT 'KAJI'
...
```

It is not allowed to provide multiple default values for a single column.

If multiple default values are allowed then which value will be used as the default(How DB will decide it)? That's why it is very obvious that there should be only one default value. I Hope, I am clear.